# How to generate unique numbers or codes from unique large strings in Java?

Tags: java

I have a table as follows:

```
+---------------+--------------+
| StringColumn  | DoubleValues |
+---------------+--------------+
| string value 1| val1         |
| string value 2| val2         |
| string value 3| val3         |
| string value 4| val4         |
| string value 5| val5         |
| string value 6| val6         |
| string value 7| val7         |
| string value 8| val8         |
| string value 9| val9         |
+---------------+--------------+
```

In the above table, the `StringColumn` strings are guaranteed to be unique. However, as they will potentially large in production, I want to generate unique hash strings for each values in `StringColumn`. Then use this hash strings to convert the above table in a `HashMap` in the hope of reducing the `HashMap` object size when exported to a file.

Which algorithm should I use to generate the hash strings so that in production I can use the same algorithm to generate same hash strings and then check in the exported hashmap for lookup?

**Note:** It is okay if the strings are not reproducible from the hash strings. Only limitation is that new string lookup in the hashmap should be possible.

**What have I done so far?**

I have tried to generate sha256 hashes foreach string and then added then to the hashmap. But generating sha256 hashes seems slow from the articles I found on the internet. Please suggest a better and fast solution.

Comment: What data structure currently stores this table?  This sort of problem might be best suited to your database, not Java, layer.  Also, are you aware that if you use the strings as keys into a hash map, that it is the hashcode which will be used to bucket each entry?

Comment: Just so you’re clear, no hash guarantees unique hashes for different inputs, however the larger the hash, the less likely collisions will be. How many values in your population? Maybe `String#hashCode()` is enough. If the input is large, why not just zip each value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen table is not yet stored in any data structure. The table is to help me better describe my problem. Although, I will be getting such strings and their values during prediction model training, and I want to keep them in a small hashmap which I will then serialize to a file on disk so I don't get to use a database.

Comment: An auto increment column in a database table sounds exactly like what would solve your problem.  There are in memory databases, such as HSQL, which you can easily setup in your Java program, if you're not ready to setup a full RDBMS.  I vote for the database solution here.

Comment: @Bohemian it would be more than a million records. Is String#hashCode() good for that scenario as well? What is the limitation of hashCode()?

Comment: What did you mean exactly by “as they will potentially large in production”? Do mean large quantities of the string-number pairs? What does ˜“large” mean to you (give a likely range of quantity)? Or do you mean the string value may be large - again, specify likely numbers.  (Edit your Question to provide these further details, rather than posting as Comments)

Comment: May be a duplicate of this Software Engineering Stack Exchange question: [*Which hashing algorithm is best for uniqueness and speed?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/49550/34735)

Comment: @BasilBourque here "large" means long strings.

Comment: When you export this to a file, are you thinking you'll *only* be writing the hashes, or the strings as well? If you're writing the strings, I don't understand what you'd gain by also writing the hashes. And if you're only writing the hashes, how do you plan on extracting the strings from them when you read the file back out? More generally, if what you want is to reduce the file size -- that's compression. Why invent your own? Just use some existing technology. (Java includes zip out of the box, for instance.)